# Pre Defined CGPoints To Describe Points On the Screen

Tags: objective-c, cgpoint

In my game i have 2 point i want to start the game from which are `CGPoint` objects. Top Left bottom right (0,0) (1,1).
Instead of create the objects and initialize, There is another way to `#define` or to declare it otherwise?
When im trying to create:

```
CGPoint kTopLeft = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

At the beginning of the file i get compiler errors.
Not sure what is the best approach and would like to hear you opinion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add to .m simple const will work

```c
const CGPoint kTopLeft = {0, 0};
```

Comment: cool! that what i was looking for!
What is that syntax? { , }

Comment: @orazran That syntax performs a member-wise initialization of a `struct`.